# Return variable from on() function - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Maybe I'm just looking too close but I don't get why I'm not returning the updated variable.

**Javascript** :

```
var playlist_id="000";

$('nav').on("click", "a", function(){
    playlist_id = $(this).attr('rel');
});

console.log(playlist_id); //returns 000, instead of 111

var playListURL = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/"+playlist_id+"?v=2&alt=json&callback=?";
```

**HTML** :

```
<li><a id="one" rel="000"><img src="images/season1.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a id="two" rel="111"><img src="images/season2.jpg" /></a></li>
```

- UPDATED

I need to access the playlist_id outside of the scope of the .on() function.

Comment: console.log is getting executed before `on` click event

Comment: why it should be? You are assigning `playlist_id` as a callback for a event

Comment: Doesn't it surprise you that `console.log` runs even if you don't click? :-D

Comment: *"I need to access the playlist_id outside of the scope of the .on() function."* That's what you already achieved with your code. All that matters is *when* you access the variable. Of course putting the `console.log` statement there will log `"000"` since the click event hasn't occurred yet. But nevertheless, `playlist_id` will have the value `"111"` after that link was clicked. So I guess, you don't have a problem after all (or at least you have a *different* problem)? Or how do you think we should proceed from here?

Comment: playlist_id is set outside the .on() function. I know that it wont return until its clicked, but its not returning or overwriting the original variable, even when its clicked.

Comment: @JMP: "but its not ... overwriting the original variable" --- how do you know that?

Comment: @zerkms because Im testing the code. If its not returning on the console.log() that is outside of the function, then its not reaching the global var.

Comment: @JMP: It is! What you are doing wrong is that you are calling `console.log` **too early**, **before the event handler changes the value**. You have an observation error and make the wrong deduction. The code still "works".

Comment: @JMP: "but its not returning or overwriting the original variable, **even when its clicked**" --- so how do you test this particular case? Any code that proves your words?

Comment: Again: The value gets correctly assigned, but **not at the moment you are inspecting `playlist_id`**. If you think that JavaScript *pauses* after you call `.on` until the click event occurs, then you are mistaken. That's not how JS works and you should probably read up again on event handlers.

Comment: I understand that it runs in a sequence and I dont have a timeout, etc for the functions.

Below is a jfiddle link
//jsfiddle.net/vkXq8/ and Im trying to get each rel to be replaced when its clicked on. Its fine onload but no change happens on click.

Comment: Here, I made a fiddle to prove it to you: http://jsfiddle.net/49DRr/. Point is: your code "works" as in that the value changes. But you are accessing it *too early* in your test. There are two options now: Either you don't have a problem at all because in your real code you are accessing the variable at a more appropriate time. Or you do have a problem because you need that value at a time it's not available yet. But without more information we can't help you find a solution. We can only tell you what you did wrong in the code you posted (notice all the bold text in the comments).

Comment: @JMP: "I understand that it runs in a sequence" --- you don't :-( "no change happens on click" --- **HOW DO YOU KNOW NO CHANGE HAPPENS??** you are not checking what was changed **AFTER THE CLICK**, you are only checking **BEFORE THE CLICK**

Comment: @FelixKling With your code, you arent getting '111' if it was clicked, correct? Thats what Im trying to achieve

Comment: @JMP: I do get `111` after I clicked it. Click `111` first and then click the button. If you look at the code, you hopefully notice that I call `alert(playlist_id);` **at a different time** than you do, namely in response to the button click, not after I bound the event handler.

Comment: @JMP: `000` and `111` are clickable as well, they change the state

Comment: @JMP Your quest for knowledge will include failure friend. Not one of us on here are perfect, except maybe [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

Comment: @FelixKling You call it inside another button click, which is cool but its doesnt return '111'. It keeps returning '000' when I click "check value of playlist_id" button.

Comment: @JMP: click on `111` label on the right part. That label is what changes the state.

Comment: @FelixKling Okay I see that, I was using your code the wrong way.

Comment: @zerkms: I should have added `href` attributes...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on an observation error.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to break this down for you by explaining when things run, pay attention to the comments. Hopefully you will see that `playlist_id` is always globally accessible, you are just not thinking correctly about when its value is set.

```
var playlist_id="000";     //<-- I run first, setting playlist_id to '000'
$('nav').on("click", "a", function(){    //<-- I run second, telling my browser that when navs are clicked, to run the code inside the function to set playlist ID
    playlist_id = $(this).attr('rel');   //<-- I do not run until a nav is clicked.
    //Any time after a nav is clicked, if you open up a debugger and check the value of the variable playlist_id, you will see it will have the correct value.
});
console.log(playlist_id);  //<-- I run third. 
                           //Look at the two other statements that have run before me.
                           //What would you expect the value of playlist_id to be? Hint:000
```

I am adding a JSFiddle to *prove* once and for all that the value is globally accessible. I am keeping your code as is, but every 500ms, I am writing the value of playlist_id to the log. Open up the fiddle, watch the console log, and click around on the two images. You will see that the value is changing as you click, and that it is globally accessible.  http://jsfiddle.net/T9YkH/.

```
setInterval(function(){
    console.log(playlist_id);
}, 500);
```

Comment: Yes, that works but Im looking to overwrite the global variable.

Answer (score 0):

`.on()` always *returns* the object(s) on which it was called to facilitate chaining. In your case, it returns `$('nav')`

As per the code you have posted, the variable `playlist_id` gets assigned when a click happens. And you are trying to log it in the console, right after binding the click event, but before it is actually triggered.

Answer (score 0):

None of this helped so I'm answering the question.

This should be deleted as it doesn't help the community.

This was the solution I was looking for:

```
    var playlist_id="000";

    $('nav').on("click", "a", function(){
        playlist_id = $(this).attr('rel');
        onStart(playlist_id);
    });

    onStart(playlist_id);

    function onStart(playlist_id){
        var playListURL = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/"+playlist_id+"?v=2&alt=json&callback=?";
}
```

Comment: Haven't we shown that the value does change, which is exactly what you wanted? However, you can't get the new value before the click event happened. If that's what you want, that's just not possible.

Comment: Exactly...really  helping there.

Comment: And I repeat: Since you are not providing any context information, we can't really propose an alternative solution. All we can say is: The value does change and you can't access it where you are currently trying to access it. From there you have to continue alone.